# How to convert bytes array in image PHP?

Tags: php, image, upload

I have this code in Java for convert byte array in image.

```
final byte[] imageData = IOUtil.toByteArray(request.raw().getInputStream());
final FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("./images/" + 
imageId.toString() + ".png");
outputStream.write(imageData);
outputStream.close();
```

But in PHP i don't work.

```
$file = file_get_contents("php://input");
$photoId = $_GET['photoId'];
file_put_contents("photos/" . $photoId . ".png", $file);
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: For us PHP peasants what exactly is a byte array and what are you trying to get? I also don't think the php input stream carries files data (`php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".`). The correct way to upload a file is with the `$_FILES` array and `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: Mmh i understand, i'm trying to get an image

Comment: ...from a form?

Comment: No by this code: https://pastebin.com/xb9EMabJ

Comment: Yeah I don't know whatever code that is sorry.

Comment: What does "it does not work" exactly mean?

Comment: When i save the result of file_get_contents i don't obtains image

Comment: I do not know how to create an image in PHP from bytes

Comment: well file put contents usually does that, but my guess is that you aren't getting any file information to begin with.

Comment: If it does not contain an image - what does it contain?